# Is there a Mac OS application which prevents users from using windows-unsafe characters in filenames?

Tags: osx, file-management, filenames, macos, ntfs

I work with a lot of older Mac users and they tend to put illegal characters into the filenames they send me. I've tried to teach them not to send me files with question marks and double quotes and asterisks in the name but they say it's all too much to remember. Is there some kind of macOS application which will automatically detect and prevent them from using unsafe characters in their filenames?